# app crashed on pressing refresh button in ios app

Tags: ios

I am working on a mail app that downloads contacts from the exchange server. However, when i open a mail with lot of email ids in "to:" section, and hit the refresh button for that particluar messageview, then my app suddenly crashes. ON checking the log file, it gives me following details. The top most app is the one i am working on.

[image: Crash log screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

you can turn on Zombie object to debug,

Project -> Edit Scheme -> Dignostics

Check Enable Zombie objects

[image]